# iptables logging output?

Tags: iptables, logs

I have seen that with iptables we can log certain packets. Where does the logging happen in Linux? Which file should I check for the logs?

```
iptables -A INPUT -i wlan0 -p tcp --syn -s 10.0.0.1 -j ACCEPT
```

Answer (score 2):

The `iptables -A INPUT -i wlan0 -p tcp --syn -s 10.0.0.1 -j ACCEPT` command in your question does not specify any logging. But each iptables rule includes packet and byte counters for matching packets, so after this command you could run `iptables -L -vn`, and see the number of TCP SYN packets arrived through the `wlan0` interface with source IP address 10.0.0.1 since the creation of the rule or the last reset of the iptables rule counters (whichever was most recent).

If you use the `-j LOG` iptables target, the matching packets will be logged in the kernel log. The most recent kernel log messages are viewable with the `dmesg` command; usually the kernel log messages are also recorded by whatever logging system your Linux distribution uses.

With classic `syslog`-style logging, I would expect to see the kernel log messages usually in `/var/log/messages` (RHEL-style syslog configuration) or `/var/log/kern.log` (Debian-style syslog configuration).

On distributions using `systemd-journald` as the primary logging system, `journalctl _TRANSPORT=kernel` should output all kernel log messages currently stored by `journald`.

You can optionally specify a custom message prefix of up to 29 letters, by using the `--log-prefix` option with `iptables ... -j LOG`.
The log messages are rather long lines that will look like this (split to multiple lines with `\` for readability):

```
<timestamp> <hostname> kernel: [optional-prefix]IN=<incoming-interface> OUT=<outgoing-interface> \ 
    MAC=<destination MAC address>:<source MAC address>:<ethertype/length> \
    SRC=<source IP address> DST=<destination IP address> LEN=<packet length> \
    TOS=<type-of-service value> PREC=<precedence value> TTL=<packet time-to-live value> \
    ID=<ID field value/fragment ID> PROTO=<protocol> <protocol-specific information...>
```

The `IN=` and `OUT=` fields will be present but empty if they are not applicable: a package logged in the `INPUT` filter chain would only have the `IN=` interface specified, and in the `OUTPUT` chain only `OUT=` respectively; a packet logged in the `FORWARD` chain would have both fields filled in.

For example, a log line from an incoming TCP SYN packet logged with `-j LOG --log-prefix "custom-prefix:"` might look like this:

```
Dec 08 12:00:00 hostname.example kernel: custom-prefix:IN=eth0 OUT= \
    MAC=11:22:33:44:55:66:aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff:08:00 SRC=192.0.2.2 DST=192.168.0.1 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 \
    PREC=0x00 TTL=232 ID=12345 PROTO=TCP SPT=54321 DPT=22 WINDOW=1023 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
```

If you want to have iptables logs separate from other kernel log messages, you might set up `ulogd` (version 2.x or greater) and then use `iptables ... -j NFLOG`. On very old kernels, you might also see `-j ULOG`, but that's deprecated and should be ancient history now.